# How to retrieve username from the chat_id?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm in the process of learning how to create a telegram bot and I seem to have run into an issue haha.

I currently store the chat_ids of all the users who chat with the bot, into an SQLite database. This is to allow the bot to be able send them a message at a later time, via their respective chat_ids. However, I would also like to retrieve their telegram username, to use it as part of the message that the bot will be sending.

I know I could simply store the usernames as well when they initiate a chat with the bot, however this is probably not a good solution as users may change their username, making the usernames in the database no longer correct.

May I know if there is a way within python to retrieve the user's telegram username using their chat_ids?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `python-telegram-bot`, you can use `bot.get_chat(chat_id)` to get info such as `first_name, last_name, username`

For more info on that, visit the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `python-telegram-bot`, here's how you can retrieve currents first , last and user names:

```
first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
user = update.message.from_user
```